# DataTables - Responsive Child Rows not Displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, datatables

I have a datatable with Edit and Delete buttons. The columns of this table DO NOT display correctly if you have resized the table and the expand/collapse icons appear.

Unexpanded table:

[image]

Table not displaying correctly:

[image]

Table html:

```
 <table id="documentsTable" class="table table-bordered display hover no-wrap dataTables" style="width: 100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Document Type</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Hide Description</th>
                    <th>Hide Creation Date</th>
                    <th>Creation Date</th>
                    <th>Hide Document Saved</th>
                    <th>Document Saved</th>
                    <th>Analyst Name</th>
                    <th>Hide Doc ID</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">Edit</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center">Delete</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Miscellaneous Update</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/Documents/Render?documentID=43141">Ryanair: an update to current year guidance - $72</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>Ryanair: an update to current year guidance - $72</td>
                            <td>2016/06/18</td>
                            <td>06/18/2016</td>
                            <td>2018/01/19</td>
                            <td>01/19/2018</td>
                            <td>Aaron Wasserman</td>
                            <td>43141</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">
                                                <button type="button" class="btnEditDocument btn btn-info btn-xs delete-btn icon-fixed-width" data-toggle="modal">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                                </button>

                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">
                                                <button type="button" class="btnDeleteDocument btn btn-info btn-xs delete-btn icon-fixed-width"
                                                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteDocumentModal" data-documentID="43141">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                                                </button>

                                    </td>

                        </tr>
```

jQuery/Javascript:

```
var doctable = $('#documentsTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'lfrBtip',
        responsive: true,
        "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        "aaSorting": [],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                'orderData': [3],
                'targets': [4]
            },
            {
                'orderData': [5],
                'targets': [6]
            },
            {
                targets: 2,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                targets: 3,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            },
            {
                targets: 5,
                visible: false,
                searchable: true,
            },
            {
                targets: 8,
                visible: false,
                searchable: false
            }
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'single',
            selector: 'td'
        },
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [0, 1, 4, 6, 7]
                },
                filename: "Documents " + today.toDateString()
            }
        ],
        order: [5, 'desc'],
    });
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? I have other tables in my app that are similar, but all work correctly.

Comment: The code you posted seems to work in this test case: http://live.datatables.net/cubugafi/1/edit   Maybe you have a CSS conflict.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks.